# LeetCode: Symmetric Tree C#

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, tree, comparative-review

https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/94/trees/627

> Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (ie,
>   symmetric around its center).
>
> For example, this binary tree [1,2,2,3,4,4,3] is symmetric:
>
> ```
>     1
>    / \
>   2   2
>  / \ / \
> 3  4 4  3
> ```
>
> But the following [1,2,2,null,3,null,3] is not:
>
> ```
>    1
>    / \
>   2   2
>    \   \
>    3    3
> ```
>
> Note: Bonus points if you could solve it both recursively and
>   iteratively.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GraphsQuestions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TreeQuestions
{

/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     public int val;
 *     public TreeNode left;
 *     public TreeNode right;
 *     public TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */



    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/94/trees/627
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class SymmetricTreeTest
    {
        //     1
        //    / \
        //   2   2
        //  / \ / \
        // 3  4 4  3
        [TestMethod]
        public void ValidSymmetricTree()
        {
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);
            root.left = new TreeNode(2);
            root.right = new TreeNode(2);
            root.left.left = new TreeNode(3);
            root.left.right = new TreeNode(4);
            root.right.left = new TreeNode(4);
            root.right.right = new TreeNode(3);
            Assert.IsTrue(SymmetricTree.IsSymmetric(root));
        }

        //    1
        //   / \
        //  2   2
        //   \   \
        //   3    3

        [TestMethod]
        public void NotValidSymmetricTree()
        {
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);
            root.left = new TreeNode(2);
            root.right = new TreeNode(2);
            root.left.right = new TreeNode(3);
            root.right.right = new TreeNode(3);
            Assert.IsFalse(SymmetricTree.IsSymmetric(root));
            Assert.IsFalse(SymmetricTree.IsSymmetricIterative(root));
        }
    }

    public class SymmetricTree
    {
        public static bool IsSymmetric(TreeNode root)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return Helper(root.left, root.right);
        }

        public static bool Helper(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2)
        {

            if (t1 == null && t2 == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (t1 == null || t2 == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (t1.val != t2.val)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //make sure the MIRRORED SIDES are sent!
            return Helper(t1.left, t2.right) && Helper(t1.right, t2.left);
        }


        public static bool IsSymmetricIterative(TreeNode root)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            Queue<TreeNode> Q = new Queue<TreeNode>();
            Q.Enqueue(root);
            Q.Enqueue(root);
            while (Q.Count > 0)
            {
                TreeNode t1 = Q.Dequeue();
                TreeNode t2 = Q.Dequeue();
                if (t1 == null && t2 == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (t1 == null || t2 == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (t1.val != t2.val)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                Q.Enqueue(t1.left);
                Q.Enqueue(t2.right);
                Q.Enqueue(t1.right);
                Q.Enqueue(t2.left);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Please review for performance

Comment: This will be a top performer (it's correct). Good luck in the competition.

Comment: @DavidFisher which one?

Comment: The iterator one is the great. However, humor me and just expand your tests down one additional branch. trying both: `1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1` and `1 2 2 1 3 4 4 3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Performance

- The recursive function is as fast as I can think of.
- The iterative function should enqueue `root.left` and `root.right` instead of `root` and `root` to gain a cycle (micro-optimisation).

#### Review

- I find it weird that the null node is considered symmetric `IsSymmetric(null)`. I would throw an error for invalid input.
- Both algorithms are not able to deal with `TreeNode` instances that have a cycle (stack overflow exception vs infinite loop respectively). You will lose some performance if you guard against cycles.
- `Helper` is a public method. There is no reason for this. Make it private or local inside the public method, and perhaps rename it to `IsSymmetric`, which will not be in conflict with the public method because of different signature.
- Parameter names `t1` and `t2` are best avoided. Use full and more clear names like `node1` and `node2`.
- `Queue<TreeNode> Q = new Queue<TreeNode>();` should be written more concisely and clearly as `var queue = new Queue<TreeNode>();`.